# GNU SASL GSSAPI Example

Tags: c, sasl, gssapi

I can't seem to find an example anywhere of how to use GNU's SASL with the gssapi mechanism. I've tried starting it up like this (just guessing how the thing works):

```
        gsasl_init(&ctx);
        gsasl_client_start(ctx, "GSSAPI", &session);
```

But I get a GSASL_UNKNOWN_MECHANISM error from gsasl_client_start. Does anyone know how to use gsasl? Could someone point me to a tutorial?

Comment: 3rd link in google http://gnu.ist.utl.pt/software/gsasl/doxygen/

Comment: Your "3rd link in google" @IłyaBursov doesn't have example code how to use GSSAPI.

Comment: scroll down for 4 examples

Comment: None of those examples are for GSSAPI!

Comment: 2nd link in google https://www.gnu.org/software/gsasl/coverage/tests/gssapi.c.gcov.frameset.html

Comment: Tough crowd today!  What OS / environment are you doing this on?

Comment: That's not even on the first page of results, let alone the second result!

Comment: @SteveFriedl on Linux. I just checked the result from gsasl_client_support_p() and looks like it thinks there's no support for it. I believe I have heimdal installed...

Comment: @DavidMulder - that has to be it.  I'm looking at the source, and there's a lot of #ifdef around all the various mechanisms, including `USE_GSSAPI`, though I don't know if *only* lack of compiling can do it; it could be that support is built in but the OS doesn't have support for it (Kerberos)?  Did you build the library yourself?  EDIT: it's not compiled in, that's the only thing that can cause this AFAICT.

Comment: @SteveFriedl actually it's mit krb5 1.17 I've got installed (including devel package). I'm using distribution packages.

Comment: Thanks @SteveFriedl I'll take a look at the package (also using the gsasl distro package). It must not be compiled in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is clearly due to the library not being built with GSSAPI support; looking at the source (`libgasl-1.8.1'), the only place that can return this is:

```
// src/xstart.c
static int
setup (Gsasl * ctx,
       const char *mech,
       Gsasl_session * sctx,
       size_t n_mechs, Gsasl_mechanism * mechs, int clientp)
{
  Gsasl_mechanism *mechptr = NULL;
  int res;

  mechptr = find_mechanism (mech, n_mechs, mechs);
  if (mechptr == NULL)
    return GSASL_UNKNOWN_MECHANISM;
```

So this means it's *not* a case of the library supporting it but it can't find resources on the computer that back it up (kerberos, for instance).

When I attempted to compile this on my own system, `configure` did not enable GSSAPI because it couldn't find something important:

```
...
checking if DIGEST-MD5 should be used... yes
checking if SCRAM-SHA-1 should be used... yes
checking if SAML20 should be used... yes
checking if OPENID20 should be used... yes
configure: checking for GSS implementation (yes)
configure: auto-detecting GSS/MIT/Heimdal
configure: use --with-gssapi-impl=IMPL to hard code
configure: where IMPL is `gss', `mit', or `heimdal'
checking for libgss... no
configure: WARNING: GNU GSS not found (see http://www.gnu.org/software/gss/)...
configure: WARNING: Auto-detecting MIT/Heimdal is unreliable, disabling GSSAPI
checking if KERBEROS_V5 should be used... no
...
```

so either some underlying package is missing, you need to fetch a related but differently named package (that includes this support), or you need to build it yourself with options that enable what you want.

Comment: And you're absolutely right. I see the same error in the package build history: https://build.opensuse.org/package/show/openSUSE%3AFactory/libgsasl
I'll have to raise an issue with the maintainer. Looks like they need to specify --with-gssapi-impl when configuring to use mit krb5 (since I see the package explicitly requires the krb5-devel package).

Comment: I rebuilt libgsasl with --with-gssapi-impl=mit and it works! I also submitted a fix for opensuse.